# php mongodb query display in table

Tags: php, mongodb

Hi there I'm trying to grab info from a mongodb server and display it in an html table. And I am very confused here. So this is what I have.
The DB name is Astron_Test -> The collection is astron.objects and in this table I have the following information stored.

```
 array(
    "_id"=>100000005,
    "dclass"=>"Distributed",
    "fields"=>array(
        "Name"=>array(
            "_0"=>"Testing",
         ),
         "NameState"=>array(
             "_0"=>"PENDING",
          ),
         'setName': {
             '_0': 'test name',
          ),
```

I have the following db connection to the DB:

```
$mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://${username}:${password}@gameserver.host.com/");
$dbname = 'Astron_Test';
$db = $mongo->$dbname;
$m = "${db}->astron.objects";
```

Here is where I make the query

```
$SEARCH = $m->find(array(fields.NameState._0 => 'PENDING'));
```

and this is the issue i get when i load the page

```
Fatal error: Call to a member find() on a non-object in
```

Thanks

edit for alu
Here it is.
Credital File

```
$mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://${username}:${password}@gameserver.host.com/");
$dbname = 'Astron_Test';
$db = $mongo->$dbname;
$collectionName = 'astron.objects';
$m = $db->$collectionName;`
```

Search File

```
require ('mongo_cred.php');
         $SEARCH = $m->find(array('fields->NameState->_0' => 'PENDING'));
     foreach($SEARCH as $result) { 
        echo var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$m` variable is String in your code. 
Try this.

```
$collectionName = 'astron.objects';
$m = $db->$collectionName;
$m-find(...
```

Comment: Ok so that works now with out errors but im not getting any data returned. This is what i am using to see if it finds any data


`foreach($SEARCH as $result) {`
   
`echo var_dump($result);

  }`

Comment: Thanks. The query change to `array('fields.NameState._0' => 'PENDING')`.

Comment: Thanks so much could you buy any chance help me get the info into a table or should i create a new question?